# Eas build fails

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated, eas

Hello brothers and sisters

I'm trying to publish my first app with expo, however the build fails due to unknown reason,

please help me to solve this issue

Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
10
%.
20%.
30%.
40%
50%
60%
70%
80
%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Faster Java compilation
- Reduced memory usage
- Support for running on Java 20
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html
  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Configure project :
> Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava
> NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Configure project :app
> ℹ️  [33mApplying gradle plugin[0m '[32mexpo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin[0m' (expo-dev-launcher@3.6.6)
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393".
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" ready.
> Installing NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" finished.
> Configure project :expo-modules-core$android-annotation
> Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Configure project :expo
> Using expo modules

- [32mexpo-application[0m (5.8.3)
- [32mexpo-barcode-scanner[0m (12.9.2)
- [32mexpo-camera[0m (14.0.4)
- [32mexpo-constants[0m (15.4.5)
- [32mexpo-dev-client[0m (3.3.8)

  - [32mexpo-dev-launcher[0m (3.6.6)
  - [32mexpo-dev-menu[0m (4.5.5)
  - [32mexpo-device[0m (5.9.3)
  - [32mexpo-file-system[0m (16.0.6)
  - [32mexpo-font[0m (11.10.2)
  - [32mexpo-image-loader[0m (4.6.0)
  - [32mexpo-image-manipulator[0m (11.8.0)
  - [32mexpo-image-picker[0m (14.7.1)
  - [32mexpo-json-utils[0m (0.12.3)
  - [32mexpo-keep-awake[0m (12.8.2)
  - [32mexpo-linear-gradient[0m (12.7.1)
  - [32mexpo-location[0m (16.5.3)
  - [32mexpo-manifests[0m (0.13.2)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core[0m (1.11.8)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core$android-annotation[0m (1.11.8)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor[0m (1.11.8)
- [32mexpo-notifications[0m (0.27.6)

  - [32mexpo-print[0m (12.8.1)
  - [32mexpo-sharing[0m (11.10.0)
  - [32mexpo-web-browser[0m (12.8.2)

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> Android gradle plugin: 8.1.1
> Gradle: 8.3
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" ready.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.